# ASP.NET MVC - More kinds of users logged in at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

First of all, I've tried searching a lot on this subject but I didn't feel like it would directly help my issue so I figured I could ask directly.

My situation is as follows: I am working on an e-shop, and basically I have two kinds of users in my application - a User and an Administrator. They both have exclusive access to two parts of the application, obviously a User can only use the front-end shop, while Administrator can only use the back-end administration. Users can register on their own, while an Administrator can only be created by another Administrator (this means that at least one Admin is pre-created by me, but I think that's okay).

Now, the logins for the two kinds are also different, I don't intend to use the "administrator can also be a user" paradigm, so an ApplicationUser login can be either for User or an Administrator, not both.

The problem I'm running into is the fact (logical though), that I don't know how to separate these two kinds of users, so they can be used on the same machine simultaneously. For example, I could be a regular customer logged in on the front-end with login X (username, password), while I could have another tab open where I'm logged in in back-end as an admin with different login Y.

Is it possible to do this with one ApplicationUser (the one that Identity pre-creates for you), or should I have to separate them somehow?

My classes are connected through Entity Framework foreign keys, so ApplicationUser, then I have Administrator that has a virtual property that is connected to an instance of ApplicationUser, and the same is with Customer.

Could you help me, point me in a direction (the more specific, the better probably, I'm not very experienced in this field) of how could I solve this?

Comment: No need to separate the admin login storage from the normal user, use same ApplicationUser table with a flag (Is Admin) or a foreign key to another table called UserType ( admin, user, ...etc) , you can browse one user per browser since all the details of the login is stored in the cookies, you can open user in chrome and admin in fire fox.

Comment: Yes, I do have a flag in ApplicationUser, but even if I accept the fact that my original request can't be fulfilled, I don't know how to restrict the user so that Admin can't do what User can and vice versa (Admin on the front-end should appear and have the same abilities as a not-logged user, customer that is not registered). And logging out the Admin whenever he looks at the front-end seems uncomfortable to me.

Comment: try to use Areas in MVC, and give option to the admin to view the application as user with readonly access, this will enrich your application, so in this case no need to logout